# How Can I Use Nested Loops on Python

Tags: python

I saw an example about using nested loop in python.

```
students = [['Igor', 'Sokolov'], ['Riko', 'Miyazaki'], ['Tuva', 'Johansen']]
for student in students:
   for name in student:
       print(name)
   print()
```

I want to use same thing below:

```
def id_validator(verified_ids,feedback_ids):
    for ids in id_validator:
        for x in ids:
            print(x)
    
    
    
id_validator([5, 8], [5,8,30,50])
```

I expected to see
5
8
5
8
30
50
but I got a Type Error:'function' object is not iterable

Comment: see: https://onlinegdb.com/yZW_A08jE

Comment: or: https://onlinegdb.com/jzMntWCHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the same name `id_validator` for both the function and the loop variable! to fix this, you need to use a different variable name for the loop!

so check this out:

```
def id_validator(verified_ids, feedback_ids):
    for ids in [verified_ids, feedback_ids]:
        for x in ids:
            print(x)

id_validator([5, 8], [5, 8, 30, 50])
```

output will be `5 8 5 8 30 50`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over both `verified_ids` and `feedback_ids` and prints each element.
for exmaple

```
def id_validator(verified_ids, feedback_ids):
    [print(x) for ids in [verified_ids, feedback_ids] for x in ids]

id_validator([5, 8], [5, 8, 30, 50])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I had created new list which is combination of two list and iterate over it. Instead of '+' you can also use extend function. Here my assumption is both the list having same number of rows.

```
  def id_validator(verified_ids, feedback_ids):
        for x in (verified_ids + feedback_ids):
                print(x)
```

Note : I skipped using nested loop